# Could not resolve '#/app/<something1>' from state 'app.<something2>'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

`$state.go('#/app/list',{ 'id':id});`

return with this error :

```
 Could not resolve '#/app/list' from state 'app.myPage'
```

this is how I defined the relevant state in myApp.js :

```
  .state('app.list', {
    url: "/lists/:listId",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/listDashboard.html",
        controller: 'listDashboardCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

    .state('app.myPage', {
      url: "/myPage",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/myPage.html",
          controller : 'myPageCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

how can I make it work?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$state.go()` expects the **state name** as a first parameter **`to`** (not *url*)

```
// instead of this
//$state.go('#/app/list',{ 'id':id});
// we should use this
$state.go('app.list',{ 'id':id});
```

Check the doc for `$state` service

[`$state.go(to, params, options)`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

> Absolute state name or relative state path. Some examples:
>
> - `$state.go('contact.detail')` - will go to the contact.detail state
> - `$state.go('^')` - will go to a parent state
> - `$state.go('^.sibling')` - will go to a sibling state
> - `$state.go('.child.grandchild')` - will go to grandchild state